# Which is the best way to backup or syncronize 130GB data via FTP

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

I have 120GB of data on one of my drive.
We have online FTP account with 500GB space.

Now i want that whole data should be uploaded to FTP. and every time the data which is modified that should only be uploaded

I used many softwares but the problem is that the data is very large
I think it will take about 1 month to fully upload it . But when i press cancel then it again starts from beginning.

Is there any way that first it sees which files are on that server and then updates only those which are modified.

I am using window 2008 server

Answer (score 7):

FTP is already bad as it is. Nobody should use FTP anymore, especially in a situation like this. Please let FTP die.

As to answer your question, you want to use [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/). We use it for data pools much larger than yours (~10 TB) and it works great.

PS: yes, it works on Windows, although probably not as well as on *nix.

Comment: My upload speed is 90KB/s .and can i pause rync or what will happen if my server restarts while transfering files

Comment: @Mirror51, rsync has excellent resume/update functionality.  It was specially designed to handle updating files over unreliable links.

Comment: I don't want to upload on any drive i want to upload online so that i can access it. But RSYNC has no options for FTP

Answer (score 4):

You're going to hate this, but the best way to do it, even with that much FTP space, is put it on tape.

Online backups might seem neat, but - and it's a big but - you are going to be in serious trouble if you ever have a disaster and need to get all that data back *right now*.

And don't forget to backup the OS and any apps running on your server too.  Getting data back is easy, getting your OS and apps back and reconfigured *exactly* the way they were before is hard.

Answer (score 0):

agree, rsync is the answer. Unlike FTP or COPY/MOVE which sync file/folders, rsync sync's the content in a file.

eg:

1. Source has 100 files and Destination has 50 of these 100 files - rsync will only copy the missing/updated files
2. Source & backup have the same set of files, but different versions - rsync will only update the files with the updated content, not the entire file itself.

rsync is content replication so it works best, takes a while for the 1st run though.

Comment: But what about if my destinantion is on internet not physical computer

Comment: You would still be able to access it via an IP/FQDN right?

Comment: no i don't have ip its the online backup utility with FTP details

Comment: hmmm...if its a 3rd party/product kinda solution, u might want to call them to find out if they would support rsyncy (unlikely though)